# Elements switch places on compilation?

Tags: c++, arrays, element, bit

I've been running into this really odd bug where a **element of my array will swap places with another**. I can solve the issue by manually changing the elements before compiling but for ease of access I want to keep it the way it is. My goal was to compare bits and store the result in an array. There is no function I actively call after I call that function so it doesn't change the array itself. It does the exact same thing when I declare the array as constants.

Here's my array:

```
int myconsts[8][8] = {
    { 6, 10, 0, 9, 14, 6, 6, 7 }
};
```

My issue as that number 14 (`myconsts[4]`) and 7 (`myconsts[7]`) would randomly swap places. Here's how I compare bits in my function

```
std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 8> myfunct(int arr[][8]) {
    std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 8> arr2;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        std::bitset<4> num1(arr[0][i]);
        std::bitset<4> num2(arr[1][i]);
        std::bitset<4> num3(arr[2][i]);

        int no;
        int no2;
        int no3;

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            int sum = 0;
            std::cout << num1[x] << "   Num: " << num1[0] << num1[1] << num1[2] << num1[3] << std::endl;

        }
        std::cout << " " << std::endl;
        i++;
    } while (i < 8);
    //just testing the logic
    arr2 = { 0 };
    return arr2;
}
```

Output:

[0]

```
0   Num: 0110
1   Num : 0110
1   Num : 0110
0   Num : 0110
```

[1]

```
0   Num : 0101
1   Num : 0101
0   Num : 0101
1   Num : 0101
```

[2]

```
0   Num : 0000
0   Num : 0000
0   Num : 0000
0   Num : 0000
```

[3]

```
1   Num : 1001
0   Num : 1001
0   Num : 1001
1   Num : 1001
```

Here is where it swaps positions with the original element[7]!
[4]

```
0   Num : 0111
1   Num : 0111
1   Num : 0111
1   Num : 0111
```

[5]

```
0   Num : 0110
1   Num : 0110
1   Num : 0110
0   Num : 0110
```

[6]

```
0   Num : 0110
1   Num : 0110
1   Num : 0110
0   Num : 0110
```

[7]

```
1   Num : 1110
1   Num : 1110
1   Num : 1110
0   Num : 1110
```

It's elements[0..7], every space in between represents a new element. I'm not sure if it's the same on all compilers.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I wasn't sure what exactly to search for to get a direct answer.

Comment: What *evidence* do you have that the elements have switched places?  You have not shown us any output.

Comment: `std::bitset` is working on bits, not bytes. Intiger is at least 16 bits, you have 4 bits in bitset. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: What's your goal with that function?

Comment: @IspasClaudiu I was going to use it to compare bits but i've seem to ran into this weird bug and had no idea where to look first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see what you are describing.

Here is my annotations on your output:

```
0   Num : 0111  // This is 2 + 4 + 8 = 14
1   Num : 0111
1   Num : 0111
1   Num : 0111

0   Num : 0110 // This is 2 + 4 = 6
1   Num : 0110
1   Num : 0110
0   Num : 0110

0   Num : 0110 // This is 2 + 4 = 6
1   Num : 0110
1   Num : 0110
0   Num : 0110


1   Num : 1110 // This is 1 + 2 + 4 = 7
1   Num : 1110
1   Num : 1110
0   Num : 1110
```

It looks like you just dumped: `..., 14, 6, 6, 7 };`
which are the final 4 elements of your array.

**I'd say everything looks correct.**

Perhaps you are reading your bits backwards on screen, since LSB (least significant bit) is ***typically*** put on the **far right**, and you've put it on the **far left**.

But your code is working fine.

Comment: Oh my god I'm an idiot. I was reading it backwards. I'm not software engineer I'm still new to some of this.

Comment: That made me feel really stupid. Thanks!

Comment: Your ***ego*** made you feel stupid.  You're not a software engineer, but you think you found a compiler bug??  You wrote, to a board *filled* with software engineers, *"if you don't understand 4 bit binary this may be a struggle"*.   (no, it is not a struggle for any of us).

Comment: Perhaps I've found myself to the wrong forum. I was not trying to appear as an undesirable nor was I even aware this site was full of engineers on that scale. I've just happened to think this would be the most reliable source for help. I'm just a kid who programs his dreams

Comment: Don't worry about it @Countchocula, even getting unexpected responses to your questions can be a useful learning experience. As you have discovered here, how things are worded matters. Pleased you have fixed it!